# Alfresco attached word document can't online edit with ms office

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Everything work fine but I can't edit online MS Office documents.
When I click on "Edit online" for excel/word file Excel/Word application starts but I have message:

> "Sorry we can't open http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/MG/documentLibrary/Test/curruculum.docx"

Then appear message that Document couldn't get access to that file.
As a client I have  MS Office 2016.
Thanku You for any help

Comment: If you go to that URL in your browser, does it work? And are you trying to edit it on the server or a client? (That URL will only work on the server for obvious reasons)

Comment: When you installed Alfresco did you use the installer? If so, did you enable installing AOS?

Comment: While installed alfresco, I used  bin file for Ubuntu machine,I didn't find any AOS options, Please help me  with reference

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco has to be configured to run on SSL environment, Check the below link:
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/configure-ssl-prod.html

If you are running a non-production environment then you may try to lower the security levels in the local registry to allow MS Office to interact in a non-SSL(http) way with Alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change share.host=127.0.0.1 in your alfresco-global.properties file to the servers' DNS Name, like alfresco.domain